Missing Launch new terminal + button
Launch new terminal '+' button missing from the default terminal. VS Code crashed few days ago since then this is missing in my default profile




Right click the ... menu.
Click New Terminal to toggle its visibility on.

screenshot of menu

wel, yeah right click works if I want only powershell terminal. but for my application setup, usually i have one git cli, docker cli, couple wsl (ubuntu) and couple psh terminals. the ... option gives me option to launch another powershell terminal, not the other options
